# \hyphenation{...} conflict with TIPA

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, tipa

Hyphenation exceptions defined with `\hyphenation` are not taken into account if the string to be hyphenated contains TIPA diacritics. However, manually inserting hyphenation points produces the expected result. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tipa, newunicodechar}

\hyphenation{bahiḥ-sva-vapuṣo}

\newunicodechar{ḥ}{\textsubdot{h}}
\newunicodechar{ṣ}{\textsubdot{s}}

\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}
   bahiḥsvavapuṣo
   bahiḥ\-sva\-vapuṣo
}
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
bahiḥsvavapuṣo
bahiḥ-
sva-
vapuṣo
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your tag is correct and you really compile with lualatex: Don't use the tipa package and newunicodechar:

```
\documentclass{article}


\hyphenation{bahiḥ-sva-vapuṣo}


\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}
   bahiḥsvavapuṣo
   bahiḥ\-sva\-vapuṣo
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd prefer not to use TIPA, but the font I have to use doesn't contain the necessary diacritics (precomposed or not).

Comment: the tipa commands take the diacritics from a different font. So they will break hyphenation. You should better try to find a solution which don't use them.